# InnerHTML says NAN on update

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to recreate the look DM-2 flight software, considering it was written in JS. I am trying to make a countdown clock. But when I go to update the innerHTMl, it spits out NAN, and the function does not repeat. Any clues would be helpful.
**HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dragon OS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="statusBarContainer">
        <button id="statusCloseButton" onclick="hideStatusRight()"><p id="closeButtonText">Close</p></button>
        <div id="statusBar">
        <h1>State:</h1>
        <h2 id="statusState">Startup</h2>
        <h1>T+:</h1>
        <h2 id="statusTplus">-60</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="topBar">
        <button class="borderButton">Home</button>
        <button class="borderButton">Attitude</button>
        <button class="borderButton">Target</button>
        <button class="borderButton">Orbit Info</button>
        <button class="borderButton">Docking</button>
        <button class="borderButton">Procedures</button>
        <button class="borderButton">Communication</button>
        <button class="borderButton">Vehicle</button>
        <button class="borderButton">Calculator</button>
        <button class="borderButton redText" onclick="abort()">Emergency</button>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="statusUpdate.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
var displayState = document.getElementById("statusState");
var displayTplus = document.getElementById("statusTplus");
var state = {
    altitude : 0,
    abort : false,
    pitch : 0,
    yaw : 0,
    roll  : 0,
    inAtmopshere : true,
    TPlus : -60
};
setInterval(checkStatus(), 1000);

function checkStatus(){
    state.TPlus++;
    displayTplus.innerHTML = state.Tplus;
}
function abort(){
    state.abort = true;
    displayState.style.color = "red";
    displayState.innerHTML = "ABORT";
}
```

Comment: state.Tplus should be state.TPlus

Comment: Well, I am stupid. But now it won't continue to update, it only shows -60 and nothing more, no countdown.

Comment: statusTplus not displayTplus

Comment: displayTPlus is statusTPlus, as defined as the second variable

Comment: It appears to be an issue with set interval rather than inner html or the function itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it gives the result of `checkStatus`, which returns nothing, to the `setInterval`.

You should remove the brackets in this line: `setInterval(checkStatus(), 1000);`, like this: `setInterval(checkStatus, 1000);`, to give a reference to the function itself.

Comment: Fixed it! Legend! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Two things

1. in setInterval, either user `setInterval(function(){checkStatus()}, 1000);` or `setInterval(checkStatus, 1000);`
2. use `state.TPlus` instead of `state.Tplus`

   setInterval(checkStatus, 1000);

   function checkStatus(){
       state.TPlus++;
       displayTplus.innerHTML = state.TPlus;
   }

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ranjitsss/2nk7evds/2/